# Simple supercapacitor fast charging circuit

Tags: circuit-design, supercapacitor

I have some 2.7 V, 500 F supercapacitors and I would like to quickly charge them from two 18650 VTC6s in parallel.

I made this simple circuit and I would like to make sure it works before I build it.

The purpose of the circuit I designed should be to quickly charge the capacitor, and as soon as it reaches the maximum voltage (2.7 V) turn off the charger so that the capacitor is not damaged.

Circuit: [image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: I tried to simulate it with https://www.falstad.com/circuit/ and it seems to work, but i want to be 100% sure it will work

Comment: It doesn't look like it'll work to me. The collector of the BJT is connected to the gate of the MOSFET and no other connection seems highly dubious. It's impossible to see how the BJT base can receive any bias current or voltage that is at all useful. Did you just randomly shift components around trying scenario after scenario until the simulator appeared to indicate something is working?

Comment: yes, I'm not very experienced

Comment: NPN emitter is higher than base. N.G.

Comment: you chose all the wrong component polarities

Comment: Using high current charger with a linear method is extremely hot. Learn to use SMPS

Answer (score 2):

How fast is fast?  To charge up in 10 seconds, it would take a constant current of 135 A.  If you limit the current to the FET's continuous rating (37 A) it would take, coincidentally, 37 seconds.

The circuit has issues.

Except for the FETs Rdson, there is nothing limiting the charging current.  That is a peak current of 254 A.  That's a lot, way more that the device's absolute max pulsed current rating (180 A).

There is nothing to assure that the FET will turn off.  If left floating, internal gate charge can keep the FET turned on for many seconds.  This defeats the intent of the circuit.  To fix this, add a 10 K resistor from the gate to the source.

The circuit function is not at all clear from the way the schematic is drawn.  Re-drawing it, the transistor's (reference designators!) emitter is tied to the 4.2 V source, the most positive voltage in the circuit.  The transistor never turns on because the base never can be 0.6 V above the emitter.

Even if the transistor somehow did something, the FET probably will not turn on because it is not a logic-level device.  It is characterized for full enhancement at 10 V gate-to source, and the max threshold voltage is 4 V.

One way to fix this is to move the FET so it is between the cap cathode and GND, and change the driving circuit to match.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, i will try to fix the circuit

Comment: Because the cap is so large, the amount of time you want the charging to take makes a very big difference in the sizes of the circuit components.  With current limited to 37 A by a resistor, the cap will charge in 57 seconds and the resistor must be rated for 100 W.   What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was thinking of building a portable spot welder, in this case the electrodes will make contact for less than 1 second so I assume that the capacitor does not discharge completely, I would like it to recharge in at least 1.30 minutes between a weld and the other

Comment: Don't expect a  detailed design solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Every part in my design serves a purpose, but I do not know what your specs are;

Mine are ; **10A CC, 3.1V CV  10% tolerance. 40 watt heat sink**. (water cooled or CPU type)

- 10A max 10% tolerance.  ( can be adjusted with **Rs magnet wire** with heat sink)
- 3.1V limiter adjusted by  3.1V LED used as a Zener  and careful ratios of PNP bias.
- every part is critical and serves a purpose but I chose your Diodes Inc NFET.
- your design had a lot of problems, which I won't go into.

[image]  let me know if you want my simulation.

Sim speed is 10x real-time speed, cursor will show actual time.  You can adjust sim speed with slider and slow down and change any part value.

Charge time is 2m:40s from 0V.  ESR was not provided for 500F cap.

---

The normal Sequence is start with >=10A then when close to target voltage sense LED turns on, then when shutdown, Green LED on left turns On at ready and other turns off.  If there is a pulse load I would expect both LEDs to toggle back and forth .(top up (R) and shutdown (L))

---

### **Another variation is 2.62V OVP  13A OCP **

[image: ![enter image description here]   Both Red , GREEN LEDS on at end of charge so it doesn't latch off.  Interactive dummy load switch added.
But it would be far easier to design with an IC or Op Amps.